# awk field separator to split specific column does not work as expected, $0 returns unsplit record?

Tags: awk, split, field

I'm trying to split a record by underscore. Originally it was about `_` and `.` as FS and only for the first column. But right now it appears that no splitting works at all?

```
cat test_file.tsv

mg.reads.per.gene_bcsZ_A1.tsv   contig_21128    476
mg.reads.per.gene_bcsZ_A1.tsv   contig_3712     1774
mg.reads.per.gene_bcsZ_A2.tsv   contig_38480    184
mg.reads.per.gene_bcsZ_A2.tsv   contig_62779    1154
mg.reads.per.gene_bcsZ_A4.tsv   contig_115486   113
mg.reads.per.gene_bcsZ_A4.tsv   contig_14345    937
mg.reads.per.gene_bcsZ_A5.tsv   contig_19362    426
mg.reads.per.gene_bcsZ_A5.tsv   contig_53656    31
mg.reads.per.gene_bcsZ_A6.tsv   contig_100190   26
mg.reads.per.gene_bcsZ_A6.tsv   contig_23343    164
```

and I've tried numerous variants such as

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = _ } ; {print $0}' test_file.tsv
awk 'BEGIN { FS = '_' } ; {print $0}' test_file.tsv
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "_" } ; {print $0}' test_file.tsv
awk 'BEGIN { FS ="_" } ; {print $0}' test_file.tsv
awk  -F'_' '{print $0}' test_file.tsv
awk -F"gene" '{print $0}' test_file.tsv
```

and it gives the unchanged output. I was expecting:

```
mg.reads.per.gene   bcsZ    A1.tsv   contig 21128    476
mg.reads.per.gene   bcsZ    A1.tsv   contig 3712     1774
mg.reads.per.gene   bcsZ    A2.tsv   contig 38480    184
mg.reads.per.gene   bcsZ    A2.tsv   contig 62779    1154
mg.reads.per.gene   bcsZ    A4.tsv   contig 115486   113
mg.reads.per.gene   bcsZ    A4.tsv   contig 14345    937
mg.reads.per.gene   bcsZ    A5.tsv   contig 19362    426
mg.reads.per.gene   bcsZ    A5.tsv   contig 53656    31
mg.reads.per.gene   bcsZ    A6.tsv   contig 100190   26
mg.reads.per.gene   bcsZ    A6.tsv   contig 23343    164
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

EDIT: yes I did: "It is a common error to try to change the field separators in a record simply by setting FS and OFS, and then expecting a plain ‘print’ or ‘print $0’ to print the modified record." (awk manual, "understanding $0")

EDIT: and to reach the final goal (splitting by _ and . only in the first column, this one works (at least in one line separated by ";"):

```
    awk 'BEGIN { OFS = "\t" }
  {
  split ($1, a, "_") 
  split (a[3], b, "\\.") 
  print $2, a[2], b[1]
  }' test_file.tsv
```

output:

```
contig_21128    bcsZ    A1
contig_3712     bcsZ    A1
contig_38480    bcsZ    A2
contig_62779    bcsZ    A2
contig_115486   bcsZ    A4
contig_14345    bcsZ    A4
contig_19362    bcsZ    A5
contig_53656    bcsZ    A5
contig_100190   bcsZ    A6
contig_23343    bcsZ    A6
```

Comment: What do you expect `print $0` to print out? That's the whole line. If you want the first value, do `print $1`.

Comment: I would like to see no more `_` in the whole line and hence 6 columns instead of 3

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: what would I do to get the whole line printed (with awk) to see whether the split worked? So do get the expected output mentioned above?

Comment: I edited the question as apparently I wanted awk to do something in a wrong way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$0` is the whole line in awk.

```
 awk -F_ '{$1=$1;print}' sample.csv
```

Input field separator is `_` and default output field separator is space. 
`{$1=$1;print}` rebuilds fields based on the output separator and print them all.

output:

```
mg.reads.per.gene bcsZ A1.tsv   contig 21128    476
mg.reads.per.gene bcsZ A1.tsv   contig 3712     1774
mg.reads.per.gene bcsZ A2.tsv   contig 38480    184
mg.reads.per.gene bcsZ A2.tsv   contig 62779    1154
mg.reads.per.gene bcsZ A4.tsv   contig 115486   113
mg.reads.per.gene bcsZ A4.tsv   contig 14345    937
mg.reads.per.gene bcsZ A5.tsv   contig 19362    426
mg.reads.per.gene bcsZ A5.tsv   contig 53656    31
mg.reads.per.gene bcsZ A6.tsv   contig 100190   26
mg.reads.per.gene bcsZ A6.tsv   contig 23343    164
```

Comment: so $1 = $1 basically changes nothing, but forces awk to "reload"?

Comment: @crazysantaclaus it uses to rebuild the record you can get more info here: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Changing-Fields.html

Comment: This has caught me so many times, because I'm an infrequent awk user. The assignment of a field forces the recompute fields with FS. Also you can call each field in a loop: `{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf $i; print ""}'`

Answer (score 1):

You're misunderstanding the use of the field separator in Awk. Awk's field separator tells Awk what value to use to divide the columns in the input, where it defaults to whitespace.

To help you understand what's going on, here's what you're currently doing (I've reduced the data file to just 3 lines so that it's easier to manage):

```
$awk -F "_" '{print $0}' test_file.tsv
mg.reads.per.gene_bcsZ_A1.tsv   contig_21128    476
mg.reads.per.gene_bcsZ_A1.tsv   contig_3712     1774
mg.reads.per.gene_bcsZ_A2.tsv   contig_38480    184
$awk -F "_" '{print $1}' test_file.tsv
mg.reads.per.gene
mg.reads.per.gene
mg.reads.per.gene
$awk -F "_" '{print $2}' test_file.tsv
bcsZ
bcsZ
bcsZ
$awk -F "_" '{print $3}' test_file.tsv
A1.tsv   contig
A1.tsv   contig
A2.tsv   contig
$awk -F "_" '{print $4}' test_file.tsv
21128    476
3712     1774
38480    184
```

See, you've divided your output into exactly 4 columns, broken up by every time there's an underscore, which are in awk as `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, and `$4`. Note that `$0` returns all the columns joined by the field separator, which looks just like your initial input.

What you want is to swap all the underscores for spaces so that there appear to be 6 columns. This can be done extremely easily by the use of the `tr` command:

```
$ tr '_' ' ' < test_file.tsv 
mg.reads.per.gene bcsZ A1.tsv   contig 21128    476
mg.reads.per.gene bcsZ A1.tsv   contig 3712     1774
mg.reads.per.gene bcsZ A2.tsv   contig 38480    184
```

Now you've got your six columns, and you can feed the output into awk if you want after that for whatever else you want to do.

Comment: that is a great explanation! I only tried 1 h to do something that could not work ;-) but haifzhan shows me how to get the expected output within awk, therefore I will accept his answer. There is no way to accept 2 answers probably?

Comment: Nope, there's no way to accept two answers, but that's completely fine that there are two answers. Accepting an answer is just a mark to show which answer helped you the most, so it makes sense that you'll accept the other one since it helped you the most.